# List item selected shows sub items in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some code where I am trying to two list subitems if one of 3-4 items are selected. It needs to work within the code shown as:

```
<div class="chartnavigator clear-fix">
<span class="label float-left">KPIs</span>
<ul class="chartlist float-left">
    @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableCharts) {
        var classname = "float-left";                        
        if (item.ChartName == Model.DefaultChart.ChartInfo.ChartName) {
            classname += " selected";
        }
        if (item.ChartName == "VTF")
        {
            <li class="@classname"><a href="javascript:void(0);">@item.ChartDummyName</a></li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="@classname"><a href="javascript:void(0);">@item.ChartName</a></li>
        }

    }
</ul>
```

So if I have 4 list items, one "ABC", "FTG", "JNB", and "VTF". Then based on the code above, if I want to inject 2 sub list items for the first 3 to be someone like "123" and "456", then I thought I could embed another if/else like such:

```
                            if (item.selected == "true")
                            {
                            <ul class="subchartlist float-left">
                                <li class="@classname"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Actual</li>
                                <li class="@classname"><a href="javascript:void(0);">LTD</li>
                            </ul>
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
```

This does not seems to work and I was hoping to get some ideas for you all. Basically needing to check if li is selected, then show sub items.

So just to be clear, the top list items always show and the selected list item top level (menu in this case) is highlighted. Others are screened back. The sub list items (only 2 in this case) will display the same behavior.

So this image shows now with just the one row of list items.

[image: List Item Menu Now]

This is what I am after where it shows those 2 sub items with one highlighted (selected).

[image: How list item sub menu should look with this]

Thanks for any help you all can provide.

Comment: Can anyone add anything to this?